# How does IFF work?

Tags: radar, military

How does Identification Friend or Foe (IFF) work? Are radar images of friendly planes recorded, or do friendly planes have transponders on them?

Answer (score 19):

IFF systems use a transponder/interrogator combination to allow aircraft to issue challenges, receive responses, and do the friend or foe test. BAE Systems has a [transponder product page](http://www.baesystems.com/our-company-rus/inc-businesses/electronic-systems/es-product-sites/identification-friend-or-foe-iff/iff-transponders) with a little info, and Wikipedia (yeah yeah) has a [reasonably thorough description and history of IFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identification_friend_or_foe).

According to [NATO STANAG 4579](http://engineers.ihs.com/document/abstract/KTVQSAAAAAAAAAAA) (abstract):

> This NATO BRID is a millimetric wave question and answer system working in the Ka band. It comprises two main components, an **interrogator, which allows a platform to question another platform with an encrypted message**, and a **transponder, which decodes the message and replies with an encrypted answer** [*emphasis mine*]. Transponders will be fitted to all designated platforms, while interrogators will be fitted to only those designated platforms with an offensive or reconnaissance capability.

Comment: I assume these systems would be enabled in warzones. Wouldn't this give away the aircraft's position?

Comment: That's one of the reasons it's a cryptographic handshake. If the query doesn't decode properly, the transponder doesn't answer at all. Of course this means that the interrogator lights up for a moment, but there are ways to manage that... and realistically, if you're close enough that IFF matters, you're already on radar.

Comment: @keshlam However, if it does decode properly (i.e. is a friendly request), the transponder *would* light up as well, potentially giving away both their positions, wouldn't it? In this case they only need to be "close enough" to each other, not the enemy.

Comment: Call it the indeterminacy principle. A single ping giving current position doesn't say where it will be three seconds later, and that's presuming the ping can be recognized (I would assume it's spread-spectrum) and triangulated upon at all.

Comment: It looks like STONAG link is broken.