# Enemy plane detection

Tags: radar, military

Suppose that an enemy plane comes into our radar surveilled airspace, and that this plane is mimicking the signature of a friendly aircraft.

Can this tactic be recognized? Is there a way of counteracting it?

Comment: It is really unclear what you are actually even asking here. There seems to be some assumptions in your question which may not be true, but it's hard to tell because of how vague it is. If you can give more details, it may be possible to give an answer, but in its current state, there is really no way for anyone to give a clear answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "mimicking the signature of a friendly aircraft"? One thing you should look at is [IFF systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identification_friend_or_foe) (Idenfity Friend or Foe): see also [this question](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/1877/946).

Comment: @DavidRicherby that is my interpretation of the original question, see edit history

Comment: There are anti-aircraft radar that measure the characteristics of a target by advanced signal processing. But I don't imagine any military is going to ignore a potential threat purely on the basis that it looks on radar like something else - so I don't know of any great effort to produce false signatures. Normally air forces concentrate on making planes less visible to radar.